# Differentiation - Limits Equal (Possibly MVT, Rolle's or L'Hopital)

Tags: analysis, limits, derivatives

Got a quick question from a past exam paper.

If $f:R \rightarrow R$ is differentiable, and $f$ is such that $\lim_{ x\rightarrow \infty } f(x)=\lim_{ x \rightarrow -\infty} f(x)=0$ and there is a point $c$ such that $f(c)>0$, then prove that $f$ has is bounded above, and attains its maximum at a point $x_0$ where $f'(x_0)=0$.

P.S - Sorry about the formatting, I'm a bit new to this :|

Comment: Hint: Find an interval $I=[-a,a]$ such that $|f(x)|<f(c)$ for all $x\notin I$. What can you say about the maximum value of $f$ on $I$?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that as long as you consider a sufficiently large compact set you can apply Weierstrass Theorem.

the fact that the function goes to $0$ with $|x| \to \infty$ implies that for each $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $M > 0$ such that $|f(x)| < \varepsilon$ for all $x$ such that $|x| > M$.

If you now take, for example, $\varepsilon = f(c)$ you are allowed to look for the maximum in $[-M,M]$, where Weierstrass Theorem holds, proving boundedness and the existence of a maximum.

The fact that $f'(x_0) = 0$ is a classical result, I guess you do not have doubts about this.